# Shift centred div to the right

Tags: css

I have a div called target which is centred and displayed over a google map when you pan to a map marker, i have since added a menu to the left of the map which means that when the google map pans to a marker it is no longer the centre of the screen.

I need to move the div to the right but I can't seem to move it.

```
#target {
    position: fixed; 
    display: none; 
    width: 51px; 
    height: 51px; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin: -40px 0 0 -26px; 
    background: url(../img/target.png) no-repeat center bottom; 
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to rectify your problem by playing a bit with the margin. Change the 4th value by adding a positive value so that it is greater than -26px. Such as:`margin: -40px 0 0 20px;`.

The 4th value in `margin` specifies the left margin value, which will shift your div to the right.

#### Alternatively

You can wrap the map and target div in a separate div from the menu, but you must change the target `position` value to **relative** or **absolute** instead of **fixed**:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="position:relative;"> <!-- map and target wrapper div. make sure this is position: absolute OR relative so that positioning will reference this div. -->
        <div id="map">...</div>
        <div id="target"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

With this alternate solution, the target and the map are aligned to the same div, almost as if they're in their own window.

Comment: i think the wrapper option is the way to go, so it is in the correct position when the window is resized.

problem is, if i add the wrapper the map doesn't load at all?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information I can only guess, but I think the `position` attribute might be your problem.

The `position` attribute can have four values:

- Static (default)
- Relative
- Absolute
- Fixed

(it also have inherit but that's not really a value)

Elements with either `static` or `relative` holds their "box" on the page, meaning it still reserves its original space.

On the other hand, elements with either `absolute` or `fixed` actually gives their space back and let other elements fill that space. Instead, it positions itself according to other elements. For `absolute` it is the closest parent with position set to either `relative` or `absolute`, and for the `fixed` value it is the viewport of the browser.

This means that whatever you add to your page, your target element will not move.

I would probably change the markup so you have a div for the map view, containing the target and the actual map.

```
<body>
    ... some stuff ...
    <div id="mapContainer">
        <div id="target"></div>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    ... more stuff ...
</body>
```

And then use absolute positioning to place the target element at the center of the container.

Answer (score 0):

adjust the amount of left: property.

change 50% to 60% or adjust the amount to fit with desired position.

Answer (score 0):

With your CSS, it is not possible to shift to the right. As it is what is forcing it to center

```
position: fixed;
left: 50%; /* be in the center */
top: 50%;
```

In order to change the position to the right, remove the `left` property and update you css to read the following.

```
right: 0;
top: 50%;
```